# What does one call a time-series regression without forecasting?

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models, autocorrelation

I have a set of timeseries data like this:
[image: x vs f(x)]

I want to build a statistical model which predicts the series `f(x)` using the series `x`. However, I don't want to predict future values of either series. I only want to use known values of `x` to predict `f(x)`. I don't want to use a simple non-time-series regression because the data has very significant autocorrelation.

What is the correct term for this type of problem? I've been Googling

> time-series regression without forecasting

but that doesn't yield any helpful results. I would also be very interested if someone could recommend a technique for this type of problem.

Comment: The relationship between two time series is sometimes studied by looking at different cross-correlations.

Comment: @MichaelM Are there any cross-correlation techniques which can create a regression? I know that the two series are extremely cross-correlated with no delay/lag, but I'm trying to find a way to predict the 2nd one using the 1st one.